# trackpad non functional for newest hp pavilion dm4

Tags: hp, trackpad

I have a newest generation hp dm4 (the trackpad and mouse buttons are separate, unlike in the previous generation). The trackpad works fine in windows, but in Ubuntu the mouse is erratic and non responsive. By going up and down on the trackpad, I can sort of get the cursor to go left and right, and thats it. I think there is some software or driver problem, but that is the extent of my knowledge. I hope someone can help.

Comment: Do you get this problem in Ubuntu only?

Answer (score 1):

From the hp support forum

[Re: Problem with touchpad brand new Pavilion dm4-2015dx
Options
07-15-2011 11:22 PM](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Lockups-Freezes-Hangs/Problem-with-touchpad-brand-new-Pavilion-dm4-2015dx/td-p/748329/page/2)

> SOLVED!!  Here's what you do.   Reboot. Login. Go to Device manager and roll back the mouse driver to PS/2.  the problem is with the ALPS Driver.   You will loose  some functionality (just bells and whistles) but the touchpad and mouse will work without freezing up.   (You don't have to screw with the bios or any of that rubbish).  Enjoy your new laptop folks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing any of the mouse settings? You can read some of the info here and see if it helps [Synaptics Touchpad](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticsTouchpad) or if that doesn't help there's some more advanced debugging techniques here to find out what's wrong [Debugging Touchpad Detection](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingTouchpadDetection)